# What am I? Can you figure it out?

Tags: riddle

> I love to eat my younger brother.
>   Our Intelligience is never ending.
>   My younger brother is very famous.
>   We have days devoted to us.

A very simple riddle. *The first line is very important.* (Not to say the others aren't.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

> pi is close, as in the comment to Tyson's guess,

then maybe you are

> tau

and you eat your younger brother because

> tau = 2 * pi

Making your day

> June 28th

Further explanation:

> The letter tau was chosen to represent (2 * pi) because of its similarity in appearance to pi (tau has one leg instead of two). There is a (somewhat tongue-in-cheek) "movement" in mathematics attempting to supplant pi with tau because it makes certain trigonometric calculations easier (The distance around a circle for instance, is 2 pi radians, which is just tau.) The reference to eating is because pi sounds like pie and also because tau is greater than pi, so it "contains" pi (like being eaten). Never-ending is a reference to the transcendental nature of the numbers; the decimal expansion contains an infinite number of digits. And just as Pi Day is March 14th because pi begins with 3.14, Tau Day is June 28th because tau begins with 6.28 (3.14 times 2).

Comment: Great job! You figured it out!

Comment: Why does tau = 2*pi? Why is this 'eating' your younger brother? Why is your intelligence never-ending? Why is June 28th tau day? Sorry, but I don't get this one!

Comment: @randal'thor I added some additional explanation. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Roger - Thanks! The 'intelligence is never-ending' bit is still kind of obscure. (Also, infinite decimal expansions aren't just for transcendental numbers - try 1/3.)

Comment: @randal'thor Sorry, should have said "infinite and non-repeating".

Answer (score 3):

My guess is

> **You are MOON and your younger brother is SUN**

I love to eat my younger brother

> Solar eclipse

Our Intelligence is never ending

> Many secrets are still hidden that us (humans) still can't figure out

My younger brother is very famous

> Sun is more famous and important than Moon

We have days devoted to use

> Sunday and Monday

Comment: The sun is hardly the moon's _younger_ brother, though.

Comment: Like @Joe Z. said, how is the moon the sub's younger brother? Other than that, clever and creative answer.

Comment: The sun is older actually.

Answer (score 2):

This one is slightly obscure

> a shark baby still in the womb

I love to eat my younger brother.

> sharks will eat each other untill born for nutrients

Our Intelligience is never ending.

> the DNA in the shark has insurmountable intelligence

My younger brother is very famous

> the younger embryo's are famous caviar

We have days devoted to us.

> 14th July, national shark day

Comment: Still not it D: